# Jenkins pipeline script src directpry

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

We have pipeline script which imports share library, it was working fine earlier, But we have modified the directory path from /src to /src/main/groovy where our groovy scripts reside.  Any idea what should be done to pipeline script to understand groovy files are under src/main/groovy?

@Library('my-global-libraries') _

import com.company.ct.Action

Error
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
12:08:52  WorkflowScript: 11: unable to resolve class com.company.ct.Action

Project structure

my-global-libraries/src/main/groovy/
my-global-libraries/var/

Answer (score 0):

Groovy is very much like Java in this regard:

```
import main.groovy.com.company.ct.Action
```